# .NET: Send a text message to all instances of the same application and read it

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, synchronization, messaging

I need ability to reliably sync some chunks of textual data between all running instances of my application. What's the best way to make it?

Comment: Can you give more information?  Is this some application with multiple conncurrent users, or are you talking multiple instances on the same machine?

Comment: Multiple instances on the same machine. I thought of using window messages provided in Windows API, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you need the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). You need something to act as a server. After that it depends whether if a change happened at some application should notify the observer or the observer should request change summary from every client (at some intervals), merge it and return it to the clients. It is too complex to answer with such minimum information you provided.